# On the kernel of the surjective ring homomorphism $R[X] \to R[ab^{-1}]$ taking $X$ to $ab^{-1}$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization, ring-homomorphism

Let $R$ be a GCD domain (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain) . Let $0\ne a,b\in R$ be relatively prime elements i.e. with gcd 1. Let $K$ be the fraction field of $R$. Let $u:=ab^{-1} \in K$ . We have a surjective ring homomorphism $\phi : R[X] \to R[u]$ given by  $\phi(f(X))=f(u),\forall f(X) \in R[X]$. I can see that $(bX-a)R[X] \subseteq \ker \phi$ .

My question is: Is it true that $(bX-a)R[X]=\ker \phi$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us first prove the Lemma

> Let $e = e_{n} x^{n} + e_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \dots + e_{1} x + e_{0} \in R[x]$, with $e_{n} \ne 0$.
>   If $e(u) = 0$, then $b$ divides $e_{n}$.

In fact
$$
e_{n} a^{n} + e_{n-1} a^{n-1} b + \dots + e_{1} a b^{n-1} + e_{0} b^{n} = 0.
$$
Since $a$ and $b$ are coprime, and $b$ divides $e_{n} a^{n}$, we have that $b$ divides $e_{n}$.

Coming to the main argument, let $c = c_{n} x^{n} + c_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \dots + c_{1} x + c_{0} \in R[x]$, with $c_{n} \ne 0$, be such that $c(u) = 0$.

We claim that $c$ is divisible by $b x - a$. Let us show that we can do long division of $c$ by $b x - a$.

Since $c(u) = 0$, we have $b \mid c_{n}$ by the Lemma, so let $c_n = b d_n$. .

The first step of long division is obtained by taking
$$
c - d_{n} x^{n-1} (b x - a)
=
(c_{n-1}  + a d_{n}) x^{n-1} + \dots + c_{1} x + c_{0}.
$$
But clearly the resulting polynomial also vanishes when evaluated in $u$, so by the Lemma $b$ divides its leading coefficient, and we can continue long division.

Comment: Is $d_n=c_n/b$ ?

Comment: I  don't understand your expression for $c-d_nx^{n-1}(bx-a)$ ... how come the constant term is $c_1ab^{n-1} +c_0b^n$  ?

Comment: Sorry, those were two misprints due to a copy-and-paste rewrite. Please let me know if it looks OK now.

Comment: it looks ok now ... it should be pointed out that the facts $gcd (a,b)=1=gcd(a,c)$ implies $gcd(a,bc)=1$ and $a|bc$ and $gcd (a,b)=1$ implies $a|c$ hold in a GCD domain ...

Comment: @users, sure, although I seem to use only the second one. And thanks.